# Using twig, how to show a message on the frontend if a field is empty?

Tags: 8, theming

Using twig, I would like to show a message on the frontend if a field is empty. My question refers to a date field, but I think this question could apply to other field types.

In my event content type I have [smart_date](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_date) field with unlimited cardinality. I do not want to make this a required field, but if the field is empty I want to show a message to visitors. Something like 'No dates are currently scheduled'.

I have created a template file called field--smartdate.html.twig and into this I have pasted the content of field.html.twig my base theme (Bootstrap). Copied below.

```
  {%
    set classes = [
      'field',
      'field--name-' ~ field_name|clean_class,
      'field--type-' ~ field_type|clean_class,
      'field--label-' ~ label_display,
    ]
  %}
  {%
    set title_classes = [
      'field--label',
      label_display == 'visually_hidden' ? 'sr-only',
    ]
  %}

  {% if label_hidden %}
    {% if multiple %}
      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--items') }}>
        {% for item in items %}
          <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      
    {% else %}
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      <div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
      {% if multiple %}
        <div class="field--items">
      {% endif %}
      {% for item in items %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% if multiple %}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

I have read [Checking for empty fields in Twig templates is complicated](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2547559) And, yes it does seem complicated and I am still unsure what to do.

I have also tried the [Empty Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_fields) module but I am hoping this can be done via the theme.

So what changes must I make to the code to display a message if the field is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are in the field template is proof for a non-empty field. So you need code outside of the field template to show a message. This can be PHP like the module you've linked or TWIG in a different template.

For example:

*node.html.twig*

```
{% if node.field_example.isempty %}
  <p>Field is empty</p>
{% endif %}
```